# How can an iPhone access another non-iPhone device over wireless(Bonjour)

Tags: iphone, bonjour

i go device(my own construction with openwrt on it) that is configurated as infrastructure of my local network. I want to see that device from application on Iphone and after that send to it some data(simple short string) and recive. I read something about Bonjour but my device doesn't have that and i don't know if (and how)i can install it on my device. Any help or suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write your own Bonjour implementation on this other device. It's not too difficult, and Apple provide some good documentation on Bonjour [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/programming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002459-SW1).